# Oracle SQL - implement logic based on CASE expression result

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have following query which returns me of percentage of rows with at least one NULL in any of columns:

```
SELECT
(SUM(CASE WHEN tablea.test IS NULL OR tableb.test IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/7000)*100) "at least one NULL (%)"
FROM tablea
FULL OUTER JOIN tableb
ON
tablea.test = tableb.test
WHERE ROWNUM < 7000;
```

Query works fine to me and I am getting valid result.

But I need to do further action in tablec, based on percentage calculated in my SELECT statement. If percentage of rows with NULL is below 30% I need to insert "YES" string inside table "tablec" column "resultcol", how can I implement such a logic?

Is it for example possible to store SELECT statement result in some temporary variable which will be used in another SQL query?

Comment: use a WITH statement or just take the select above and make into an inline view then reference from your 2nd select.  There are no "variables" in SQL, unless you use pl/sql.

Comment: Is it possible to use WITH together with UPDATE table? As I said in below post, I need to update value in existing table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablec (resultcol)
SELECT 'YES'
FROM   tablea
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableb
       ON tablea.test = tableb.test
WHERE  ROWNUM < 7000
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tablea.test IS NULL OR tableb.test IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
        < COUNT(*) * 0.3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6125993737fd75943ed3683119c8e24c)*

---

#### Update:

If you want to insert a row if it does not exist or change the row if it does exist then:

```sql
MERGE INTO tablec dst
USING (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM   tablea
                       FULL OUTER JOIN tableb
                       ON tablea.test = tableb.test
                WHERE  ROWNUM < 7000
                HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tablea.test IS NULL OR tableb.test IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
                         < COUNT(*) * 0.3
              )
         THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
         END AS resultcol
  FROM   DUAL
) src
ON (1 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (resultcol) VALUES (src.resultcol)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET resultcol = src.resultcol;
```

Or, to just update it:

```sql
UPDATE tablec
SET resultcol = CASE
                WHEN EXISTS (
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM   tablea
                              FULL OUTER JOIN tableb
                              ON tablea.test = tableb.test
                       WHERE  ROWNUM < 7000
                       HAVING COUNT(
                                CASE
                                WHEN tablea.test IS NULL
                                OR   tableb.test IS NULL
                                THEN 1
                                END
                              ) < COUNT(*) * 0.3
                     )
                THEN 'YES'
                ELSE 'NO'
                END;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=15c20433e2862ef031e5eb170359859b)*

Comment: I wrongly interpreted problem, I already have table and column and I need to change column value from NO to YES. And as far I can see HAVING doesnt work with UPDATE?